# Nginx alias for port

Tags: redirect, nginx

How can I access domain.com:81 as a domain.com/dd?

That's the folders structure and what I want to reach.

```
/var/www/doamin.com (port 80) - http://domain.com

/var/www/dd (port 81)         - http://domain.com/dd
```

I use Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you cannot do such thing.
Port numbers need to be numeric (thus we call them - numbers).

If you need virtual hosts, that's different topic.

So, you can do the following:

- setup nginx to target /var/www/doamin.com on exampleLocalhost.com
- setup nginx to target /var/www/dd  on anotherExampleLocalhost.com

This way you avoid port numbers completely, using vhosts, and you will get the right content depending on the domain you target your server.

Comment: I own one domain and I want to display few apps (php, django) under one url. Can't I?

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use this port number approach, you could create an `upstream` pointing to domain.com:81 and create and `location /dd` using `proxy_pass` on domain.com server.

```
server {
    listen  localhost:81;
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html/1;
    location ~* /dd/ {
        proxy_pass  http://domain$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen  localhost:82;
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html/2;
}

upstream domain {
    server localhost:82;
}
```

I've create a `dd` dir inside my `/usr/share/nginx/html/2` dir in order to keep the `/dd` as part of the URI.

Comment: I found I don't have to use different port. But I have other question, can I point domain.com/dd to subdomain dd.domain.com?

Comment: In this case, I would use the `server_name` to match different subdomains. You can map the same IP address to various domains as long you have only one `server` tagged as `default`.